# Elasticsearch - Bool filter: date range OR field can be nul

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a **bool filter** in ElasticSearch that checks the `start_date` and `end_date` compared to today. If `start_date` or `end_date` is null, the result should still be returned.

So for example, today is 2016-08-09.

- **Item 1**: start_date: 2016-08-04 end_date: 2016-08-08   *SHOULD NOT BE RETURNED*
- **Item 2**: start_date: 2016-08-08 end_date: 2016-08-12    *SHOULD BE RETURNED*
- **Item 3**: start_date: null end_date: null    *SHOULD BE RETURNED*

Can't seem to get it to work with my current code:

```
POST _search
{
"query":{
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "range": {
                        "start_date": {"lte": "2016-08-09"}         
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "end_date": {"gte": "2016-08-09"}     
                    }
                }],
                "should": [{
                    "missing": {
                        "field": "start_date"         
                    }
                },
                {
                    "missing": {
                        "field": "end_date"      
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need something like this, i.e.:

- `start_date` must either be null or before today
- `end_date` must either be null or after today

Revised query:

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "start_date": {
                        "lte": "now"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "missing": {
                      "field": "start_date"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "end_date": {
                        "gte": "now"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "missing": {
                      "field": "end_date"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need the following query:

`(start_date <= date AND date <= end_date) OR (start_date == null) OR (end_date == null)`

Following the example at [elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/combining-filters.html#bool-filter), I would write the following clause:

```
"bool": {
    "should": [
        {"bool": 
            "must": [{
                "range": {
                    "start_date": {
                        "lte": "2016-08-09"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "range": {
                    "end_date": {
                        "gte": "2016-08-09"
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        "missing": {
            "field": "start_date"
        },
        "missing": {
            "field": "end_date"
        }
    ]
}
```

If it did not work exactly as written, I would try to see if each part of the `should` clause works (i.e. date is inside a range, start_date is not present, end_date is not present) by executing queries with these individual pieces. If all of them work, combining them inside `should` clause should work too.