# Elasticsearch - Filter by Date Range where Dates can be Null Using Filter Context

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to filter out any results that have an "Available Until" date in the past. However, if the "Available Until" date is null, I still want to return the result.

Here is the output that I need:

`Available Until Date < today` << this **should not** be returned

`Available Until Date >= today` << this **should** be returned

`Available Until Date is null` << this **should** be returned

I have looked at the following other stack overflow questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38844444/elasticsearch-bool-filter-date-range-or-field-can-be-nul) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139525/combine-elasticsearch-date-range-queries-with-null-values), however, I believe both are in query context, whereas I need to use filter context.

Below is my code for what I have so far. How would I modify this to allow results with null values in "Available Until", using filter context?

```
var baseQuery = {
    "size": 1000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
                "range": {
                    "Product.AvailableUntil": {
                        "gte": "now"
                    }
                }
            }],
            "must_not": [],
            "should": [],
            "must": []
        }
    }
};
```

Thank you for any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution is what I ended up using. By nesting the bool clauses inside of another bool clause which is inside of the filter clause, I was able to achieve my desired output using filter context.

```
var baseQuery = {
    "size": 1000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
                "bool": {
                    "should": [{
                        "range": {
                            "Product.AvailableUntil": {
                                "gte": "now"
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        "bool": {
                            "must_not": {
                                "exists": {
                                    "field": "Product.AvailableUntil"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }],
            "must_not": [],
            "should": [],
            "must": []
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to use a `bool/should` query to capture the constraint that

- either there is no `AvailableUntil` date
- or the `AvailableUntil` is later than today

The query would look like this:

```
var baseQuery = {
    "size": 1000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "Product.AvailableUntil"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                    "Product.AvailableUntil": {
                        "gte": "now"
                    }
                }
              }
            ]
        }
    }
};
```